# Code autocompletion using ropemacs on opencv python bindings

Tags: python, emacs, opencv, rope, pymacs

I'm wondering if there's a get rope-code-assist working on the cv namespace of openCV

```
import cv2.cv as cv
cv.LoadImage
```

So far I get [no match]. Is there something else I need to do?

The cv2.pyd is in the PYTHONPATH and has been built from the opencv source.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with emacs but I do know rope should have no problems with this (works great with ropevim).